# Compare Field Input with Firebase Entry

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an HTML input field where the user needs to type in a specific 6-digit password (handed to the user at an exhibition). Attached to the password on Firebase is an ID `psrID` (see attached img below).

The ID `<?= $page->psrID() ?>` is also being used to generate different pages, fetch textures for objects from my CMS etc.

There is only 1 correct password per `<?= $page->psrID() ?>` available. I can `console.log(seeds)` to show me the whole array.

If equal = It should display a success message;
If not equal = It should display sth like «wrong password»

Here's how I get the data from Firebase:

```
    var database = firebase.database();
    
    var ref = database.ref();
    ref.on('value', gotData, errData);
    
      function gotData(data) {
        var seeds = data.val();
        console.log(seeds);
      }

      function errData(err) {
        console.log('Error!');
      }
```

And here is the HTML input form:

```
<form class='seedForm' method='post'>
   <label for='seedPassword'></label>
   <input id='seedPasswordInput' type='text' name='seedPWD' maxlength='6' class='button' onfocus="this.value=''" value='Enter Pasword' style='text-transform:uppercase' />
   <input type='submit' name='button' class='button' value='Register' />
</form>
```

[image: My Firebase Realtime Database Structure]

What function do I have to write to compare the password entered by the user to the password of the ID on Firebase? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to only read child nodes where a specific property matches a certain value. In that case, you'll want to [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data):

```
var ref = database.ref();
var query = ref.orderByChild("password").equalTo("HYP4WJ");
query.on('value', gotData, errData);
```